Sonar Quality Gate API is showing wrong or incomplete results sometimes
QUALITY GATE details
Sonar way (default):

Issues:
1.Sometimes sonar report doesnot show all the conditions of quality gate for branches:

Same for main branch:


sometimes, it shows all conditions for branch, but QG passed here even though coverage was less:


Script used to fetch and print report in Github actions workflow logs:
`#!/bin/bash

set -a
echo 'FETCH QUALITY GATE STATUS'

# Extracting branch name and assigning it to a variable
CURRENT_BRANCH=$(echo "$CURRENT_BRANCH" | sed 's/refs\/heads\///')
echo "Current Branch: $CURRENT_BRANCH"

api_url="https://server.com/api/qualitygates/project_status?branch=$CURRENT_BRANCH&projectKey=$SONAR_PROJECT_KEY"
echo "API called: $api_url"

response=$(curl -s --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/CA1.crt \
  -u $SONAR_TOKEN: \
  $api_url)

status=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.projectStatus.status')
report=$(echo "$response" | jq '.')

echo " "
echo "Report:"
echo "$report" | jq -r '.projectStatus | "\(.conditions[] | "Metric: \(.metricKey)\nStatus: \(.status) (Actual: \(.actualValue), Threshold: \(.errorThreshold)) \n ")"'

if [ "$status" == "ERROR" ]; then
  echo "QUALITY GATE FAILED. PROJECT STATUS: $status"
  echo "INFO: If you want to still merge this Pull Request, please take exceptional approval from DEV Leads"
  exit 1
elif [ "$status" == "OK" ]; then
  echo "QUALITY GATE PASSED. PROJECT STATUS: $status"
else
  echo "Please re-run. Couldn't fetch status, PROJECT STATUS: $status"
  exit 1
fi`


And once it showed wrong status


API status which I printed in Github actions workflow logs:


On sonar server:



I wanted to know any alternative which I can use to fetch Quality gate report in Github actions workflow logs and fails the workflow if quality gate fails. And this I want to do this for main as well as all other branches.
Pre build Github actions also uses same API, which is unstable. So is there any other way to achieve this.
